# scrollReveal.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollreveal.js

I am using the exact code that [THIS](http://codepen.io/ComeonCreative/pen/mVjVJK) codepen uses, and my images still aren't fading in when they are in my viewport.

Im not getting any errors in the console so i dont know why it would work perfectly in codepen but not when i try to do it.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-games">
    <div class="game"></div>
    <div class="game"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/scrollreveal.js/3.0.9/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.game');
});
```

There is also some basic css..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CodePen, click on the lower-right 'Export' button to download a working non-CodePen version of this. You need to include the CSS in your head tag, which you haven't included in your question.

Also you don't need the JQuery `$(document).ready()`, but if you insist on using it you'll also need to include JQuery as a script in your HTML.